# Unable to send mail using SKPSMTPMessage

Tags: ios, objective-c, email

I am using `SKPSMTPMessage` to send emails in background and it is working too. But the problem arises in one particular case. There is a part where I have to use a string returned from a webApi as the email body. The `SKPSMTPMessage` delegate shows sending successful but the mail is never received. I have tried changing the returned string in various ways like removing newline characters and whitespace characters too. The weird part is that when I change a particular Capital (A -in approve) letter to small letter, the mail gets delivered.

The string I am using as mail body is :

```
You have new App registration Approval request. 
Name:rktest26
Email :rktest26@test.com 
Mobile
Phone:
Address:a1asssaasssa 
To Approve please click the below link. 
(some link)
ClientId=38&EmailId=rktest26@test.com&Approved=1 
To Reject please click the below link. 
(some link)
```

If I remove the string content after `Address:a1asssaasssa` part, it gets delivered.
What can I do so that the whole message gets delivered?